# How do I place a json value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am sending selected fields to an API(3rd party app) from wordpress.

This is how my data array looks like:

```
var data_array = {
  "order": {
    "customer": {
      "name": "The User"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to substitute the value of the "name" key to a javascript variable that contains a jquery selector. For example:

```
var name = j('.billing_company_name').html(result.meta_data[1].value);
```

I am thinking that the new code for the data_array will be:

```
var data_array = {
  "order": {
    "customer": {
      "name": name(variable name jquery selector)
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know the correct syntax so I can substitute the value of "name" key with the value of the jquery selector?

The final code will look like the code below:

```
j.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://mywebsite/api/orderdetails',
  cache: false,
  data: {
    "data_array": data_array
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
  },
  success: function(result) {
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
  },
  complete: function() {
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) that's an object not a 'data array' 2) While you can technically send a jQuery object in an AJAX request it's a very odd thing to be doing, that's most likely a mistake. Do you instead want to send a *property* or *attribute* of the jQuery object instead?

Comment: Actually, inside the object will be several key and values.. i have update the question details. i will be using the data_array object to be passed as an object to a POST request

Comment: Right, but the problem is that you're attempting to set the `data_array.order.customer.name` to a jQuery object, which as I stated above is very likely to be a mistake as you're sending serialised data, and not what you actually need to do. Do you instead need the `value` of the element?

Comment: yup. i need the value of the element to be place inside the value of data_array.order.customer.name

Comment: Ok, then you just need to use `data_array.order.customer.name = name.val()` (if doing it after the object is created) or `"name": name.val()` (if you do it during declaration)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please write your comment as answer? i'm going to mark it as correct

Comment: Sure, I added it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the value of the element to be place inside the value of `data_array.order.customer.name`

In this case you can use `val()` to select that property. If you want to do it as you instantiate the object, use this:

```
var data_array = {
  "order": {
    "customer": {
      "name": name.val()
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you want to do it after declaring `data_array` (which is badly named, as it's an object not an array), then you can use this line:

```
data_array.order.customer.name = name.val();
```

Comment: thanks. i was able to send details to an external web app because of your guide